# Spring + Hibernate + Spring Security configs

Tags: hibernate, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-security

I have application, which uses Spring, Hibernate and Spring Security. My goal is to have one config (.xml) file for each of these frameworks **and load them only once**. So basically I want `spring-config.xml`, `hibernate-config.xml`, `spring-security.xml` and `web.xml` as configuration files. It works now as I want, **BUT** as I look at deployment logs, there are obviously duplicate entries - beans that are loaded more than one time.

`web.xml` - http://pastebin.com/7ELvV8fS

`spring-config.xml` - http://pastebin.com/FVTcNu7L

`hibernate-config.xml` - http://pastebin.com/xXWbgAex

`spring-security.xml` - http://pastebin.com/JUycGUNA

GlassFish 3.1 deployment output - http://pastebin.com/53Bgyj2r

As you can see in output, there are few times that `spring-config.xml` is initiated. Also my custom bean in `spring-config.xml` is initiated two times.

Comment: check you server configuration, are you loading 2 apps into the container ?

Comment: Everything, is ok with server configs. I got this far: if I remove <includes> from spring-security configuration, no more duplicates, but then spring-security somehow doesn't work - says that Credentials are Bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you are loading the spring-config again in Spring-security via

```
    <beans:import resource="/hibernate-config.xml"/>
    <beans:import resource="/spring-config.xml"/>
```

you could try removing this . By the configuation below, you need not specify a separate context param for spring-security.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        classpath:spring/spring-security.xml,
        classpath:spring/spring-config.xml
    </param-value>       
</context-param>
```